# Where do the temp files go when using MiniMagick in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

I'm using MiniMagick to perform some image resizing on images uploaded through a multi-part form. I need to generate a few different types of images from the originally uploaded file. Here's the code that's performing the image processing:

```
// Generates a thumbnail image
mm = MiniMagick::Image.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', new_url))
mm.resize(thumbnail_dimensions.join("x"))
mm.write(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', "t_"+new_url))

// Generates cropped version
mm_copy = MiniMagick::Image.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', new_url))
mm_copy.crop('200x200')
mm_copy.write(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', "c_"+new_url))
```

`new_url` is the path to the image in the `public` folder. The thumbnail routine works perfectly. When the app goes to start processing the cropped version, that is where things start breaking and I can't for the life of me figure it out. I receive the following error when from this code:

```
No such file or directory - /tmp/mini_magick20110627-10055-2dimyl-0.jpg
```

I read some stuff about possible race conditions with the garbage collector in Rails but I wasn't able to resolve the issue. I tried this from the console as well and can create MiniMagick instances but receive the `No such file` error there as well. At this point, I have no idea where to go so I'm hoping someone here has some helpful suggestions. Thanks for your help!

**Details**:

- OS: Ubuntu (Lucid Lynx)
- Rails Version: 3.0.7
- Ruby Version: 1.8.7
- MiniMagick Version: 3.3

Comment: Does the crop code work if you comment out the thumbnail lines above?

Comment: Hmmm ... I haven't tried that. I'm getting back to this project now so I'll check it out and post the results.

Answer (score 7):

Did you installed ImageMagick?
If not,
try `sudo apt-get install ImageMagick`,
and then restart your webrick server

Comment: This is the actual command => sudo apt-get install imagemagick

Answer (score 3):

it's probably the race condition which is mentioned here:

https://ar-code.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35/tickets/6-race-condition-with-temp_file

here's one fix:

http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=9417&group_id=1358&atid=5365

alternatively, and probably easier, you could try this:

```
// Generates a thumbnail image
mm = MiniMagick::Image.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', new_url))
mm_copy = mm.clone   # clone the opened Image, instead of re-opening it

mm.resize(thumbnail_dimensions.join("x"))
mm.write(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', "t_"+new_url))

// Generates cropped version
mm_copy.crop('200x200')
mm_copy.write(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', "c_"+new_url))
```